# Update Persistent Storage failure - Galaxy Tab S6/Linux

Tags: flutter, persistent-storage, stream-builder

I am getting an "Update Persistent Storage" failure when running any Flutter app from my Linux computer to my Galaxy Tab S6 using "flutter clean" followed by "flutter run". This is something that just started happening after I added a few more StreamBuilders to the app I am currently working on, and it continues to happen even when I comment out those streams. Any help or ideas as to what's going on would be greatly appreciated!

```
F/OIC_SRM_DOXM(14551): UpdatePersistentStorage failed!
```

Comment: I had the same issue today. Previously I've enabled the debugger from Firebase Analytics on my device, while testing with a Xamarin Forms app. After disabling it, I was able to deploy my Flutter app on my device again.

Comment: Factory resetting my tablet I'm testing with fixed the issue